# Help on Account Validation Rule to prevent User from Changing Ownership of Account

Tags: validation-rule

I am looking to create a validation rule that prevents a user with the profile "Account Executive" or "Sales Manager" from changing the ownership of a prospect account that is owned by anyone other than the default "Sales Operations" user (ID 0054s0000035WiI).

The VR below passes the syntax check but throws an error whenever the user tries to change the account owner on accounts owned by ANY user.

```
AND(
    OR(
        $Profile.Name = 'Account Executive',
        $Profile.Name = 'Sales Manager'
    ),
    OwnerId <> '0054s0000035WiI',
    ISPICKVAL(Type, 'Prospect'),
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
)
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> '0054s0000035WiI'`.  Your rule is currently checking the final value of the owner ID.  It's no longer the Sales Op user since the current user has just changed the owner.

Comment: It works!! Thank you!!!! I had tried PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) != '0054s0000035WiI' and that hadn't worked.

Comment: @TriciaFrawley `<>` and `!=` in formulas do the exact same thing, so if one didn't work then there was likely a typo elsewhere ("smart" quotes instead of single/double quotes, missing a character from the Id, etc...)